# Whole cluster failing if one kafka node goes down?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have 3 node kafka cluster each having zookeeper and kafka. If i explicitly kill the leader node both zookeeper and kafka the whole cluster is not accepting any incoming data and waiting for the node to come back.

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 3 min.insync.replicas=2 --partitions 6 --topic logs
```

topic created using the above command.

Node 1

server.properties

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.2.4:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181,10.0.2.5:2181,10.0.14.7:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

zookeeper.properties

```
tickTime=2000 
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/ 
initLimit=5 
syncLimit=2 
server.0=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.1=analyzer1:2888:3888
server.2=10.0.14.4:2888:3888
clientPort=2181
```

The respective kafka and zookeeper for each node is in above format respectively.

When i check zookeeper status of rest of the nodes i can see a new leader. But still producer fails to send data. Also two kafka nodes not responding with below error.

```
WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 30004ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

If you want kafka logs from the available node?

```
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,607] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 12002ms for sessionid 0x2acefe00000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,608] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 12002ms for sessionid 0x2acefe00000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,709] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,709] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,709] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,709] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,866] INFO Opening socket connection to server 10.0.14.7/10.0.14.7:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,867] INFO Socket error occurred: 10.0.14.7/10.0.14.7:2181: Connection refused (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,968] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-10-08 19:40:13,968] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-10-08 19:40:14,093] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=0, leaderId=1, fetcherId=0] Connection to node 1 (/10.0.2.5:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-10-08 19:40:14,093] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=0, leaderId=1, fetcherId=0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=205463854, epoch=INITIAL) to node 1: {}. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 10.0.2.5:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) failed.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.scala:103)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetchFromLeader(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:206)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:300)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:135)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeFetch(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:134)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:117)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
```

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when you only mention one of the brokers in the KafkaProducer properties `bootstrap_servers`. My assumption is that this property is set only to the broker `10.0.2.5:9092` instead of listing all three nodes.

Although it is sufficient to mention only one of them to be able to communicate with the entire cluster, it is recommended to have listed at least two broker addresses (as a comma seperated list) to deal with such scenarios your are facing.

In case of an individual broker failure the broker might switch partition leader to active brokers as you have seen in the logs. Even though you are not listing all of the brokers in the property `bootstrap_servers` the producer will figure out to which broker (partition leader) it needs to send the data to.

Comment: in producer i have mentioned two nodes. That is not the case!!

Comment: And restarting all the node one by one is bringing back the cluster.